# Euclidean evaluation in domain of unique factorization.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have a question, and it is if a Euclidean evaluation can be defined in a general way in any unique factorization domain. I've thought that Euclidean evaluation can be defined by factoring irreducibles, but I don't know how true that is.

**EDIT**
Maybe I asked the question wrong, but what I am trying to ask is that if it is possible to define a Euclidean evulation such that a domain of unique factorization becomes a Euclidean domain. For an arbitrary UFD.

Comment: The term “Euclidean evaluation” is not standard. I think you are asking if every UFD is a Euclidean domain. No. For example, $F[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ where $F$ is a field and $n \geq 2$ is a UFD but is not a Euclidean domain.  This is also true for $\mathbf Z[x]$.

Comment: Maybe I asked the question wrong, but what I am trying to ask is that if it is possible to define a Euclidean evulation such that a domain of unique factorization becomes a Euclidean domain. @KCd

Comment: If that was true, then every UFD was a PID. KCd gives an example above that shows that this is not the case.

Comment: Every Euclidean domain is a PID by [remainder descent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/666352/242), but UFDs are PIDs [if & only if](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16759/242) if they have dimension $1\,$ (i.e. every non0 prime ideal is maximal), [for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1872824/242) $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ are non-Euclidean UFDs.

Comment: If your notion of "Euclidean evaluation" means something different than the standard denotation (i.e. division with smaller remainder) then you need to precisely define it.